# Why UnobservedTaskException?

Tags: system.reactive

Why does this code cause an unhandled exception. I would have expected the exception to be swallowed or reported in the OnError handler depending on whether the Rx subscription is disposed or not.

Is there a good way to avoid this other than writing a continuation on every task to check if it's faulted and then look at it's exception property?

I'd *thought* Rx did this for us but clearly not.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, a) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***************\nUnhandled '{0}' detected.", a.Exception.InnerException.GetType());
        };

        var d = Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.WhenAny(Do1(), Do2()))
            .Subscribe(x => { }, ex => Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Inner"));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to dispose");
        Console.ReadKey();
        d.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Task Do1()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            throw new AccessViolationException("Oops 1");
        });
    }

    private static Task Do2()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(600);
            throw new AccessViolationException("Oops 2");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered trying to do this in the Rx kind of way? `Observable.Amb(Observable.FromAsync(() => Do1()), Observable.FromAsync(() => Do2()))`

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity. I don't believe this changes the result though, you would still see an unobserved exception for Do2 (see my edit to illustrate this)

Comment: It fixes one of the errors, but the other happens outside of the observable pipeline so it's not captured. The reason is that your code can't be cancelled. Rx deals with this stuff and ends pipelines if it can, but it can't reach in to TPL and change anything - hence it is unhandled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unhandled; it's unobserved.

The unobserved exception is due to this code: `Task.WhenAny(Do1(), Do2())` and has nothing to do with Rx. The return type of `Task.WhenAny` is `Task<Task>` - that is, a future that resolves to the task that completed. In order to observe the result of this inner task (including exceptions), you need to `await` the task that completed, not the task returned from `Task.WhenAny`.

So in your code right now, you end up with an observable sequence of *tasks*, which is weird but legal. `FromAsync` returns `IObservable<Task>`, and `x` in your `Subscribe` lambda is of type `Task`.

I believe you want the result of `Do1` or `Do2` to be the actual data in the observable, and to do that, you need to unwrap that task. A "double await" is not uncommon when calling `Task.WhenAny`:

```
var d = Observable.FromAsync(async () => await await Task.WhenAny(Do1(), Do2()))
    .Subscribe(x => { }, ex => Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Inner"));
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Unwrap` method:

```
var d = Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.WhenAny(Do1(), Do2()).Unwrap())
    .Subscribe(x => { }, ex => Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Inner"));
```

Whichever works better for your real-world code.

**Update:** Sample extension method for preventing unobserved exceptions only for specific tasks:

```
public static Task IgnoreUnobservedExceptions(this Task task)
{
  Ignore(task);
  return task;
}

public static Task<T> IgnoreUnobservedExceptions<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
  Ignore(task);
  return task;
}

private static async void Ignore(this Task task)
{
  try { await task.ConfigureAwait(false); }
  catch { }
}
```

Usage: `Task.WhenAny(Do1().IgnoreUnobservedExceptions(), Do2().IgnoreUnobservedExceptions())`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that makes sense. However we still have the problem that Do2 can also throw an exception after Do1 has completed and this will go unobserved without a continuation. What I'd really like is for Task.WhenAny() to swallow any UnObservedExceptions except for when they are thrown by the first task that completes.

Comment: @user630190: That's expected behavior. [Unobserved exceptions no longer crash the process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/). If you want to know about them, then listen to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`; if not, don't listen to that event. If you want to listen to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` for other reasons but don't want exceptions from *these specific tasks* to show up there, then you'll need a continuation, preferably wrapped in an extension method.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have it implemented as a continuation. I was hoping there might be a better pattern to solve this but I guess not. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user630190: [If you use `ContinueWith`, please be sure to specify `TaskScheduler.Default`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Answer (score 1):

Rx does a wonderful job of bubbling up the errors and cleaning up after itself when any of the following occur:

- The observable is cancelled (through disposing the subscription)
- The observable completing.
- The observable hitting an error.

But for this to happen the entire computation chain needs to be under control of the observable subscription.

In your code that hasn't happened.

`Observable.FromAsync` takes a `Func<Task<T>>` and returns and `IObservable<T>`. Your `Observable.FromAsync` is returning an `IObservable<Task>` which means your parameter is returning a `Task<Task>`. And that's what `Task.WhenAny(Do1(), Do2())` is doing. That means that the inner task of `Task<Task>` is not under the control of the observable subscription.

To fix the code there are two things you can do.

The first is to fix the TPL so that it is under the control of the observable. That means making it cancellable and also unwrapping the `Task.WhenAny`.

Here's the new `Do` methods:

```
private static Task Do1(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(500, ct);
        throw new AccessViolationException("Oops 1");
    }, ct);
}

private static Task Do2(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(600, ct);
        throw new AccessViolationException("Oops 2");
    }, ct);
}
```

Now you can write your code this way:

```
using (
    Observable
        .FromAsync(ct => Task.WhenAny(Do1(ct), Do2(ct)).Unwrap())
        .Subscribe(
            x => { },
            ex => Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}"),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Inner")))
{

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to dispose");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This now works as expected.

The second thing you can do is not write this using tasks. Use pure Rx code.

Here is the alternative `Do`s:

```
private static IObservable<Unit> Do1() =>
    from x in Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
    from y in Observable.Throw<AccessViolationException>(new AccessViolationException("Oops 1"))
    select Unit.Default;

private static IObservable<Unit> Do2() =>
    from x in Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
    from y in Observable.Throw<AccessViolationException>(new AccessViolationException("Oops 2"))
    select Unit.Default;
```

Here's the main code:

```
using (
    Observable
        .Amb(Do1(), Do2())
        .Subscribe(
            x => { },
            ex => Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}"), 
            () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Inner")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to dispose");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This works too.

I much prefer the Rx way of doing it.